# JSON result not showing in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This code seemed to work a month ago but when I returned to coding this today it shows an error.
I have no problem with my back-end as I checked it. 
The code below returns:

'Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map'

```
Map data;
List userData;
Future getItems() async {
  http.Response response = await http.get("http://172.16.46.130/olstore_serv/get_items");
  data = json.decode(response.body);
  setState(() {
    userData  = data["item"];
  });
}
```

Comment: your `data` is not a map but it is a list (most likely list of maps) - the most simple way to check it is to `print(data)`

Comment: it's alreay a map,c i edited it

Comment: what do you see if you `print(response.body)`? just first 8 characters? something like: `print(response.body.substring(0, 8)); data = json.decode(response.body);`

Comment: if it starts with `[` its a list, if it starts with `{` its a map - and i am pretty sure that it starts with `[`

Comment: this is the result  =>  [["1","0

Comment: Can you please show us your response.body? so we can see the structure of your json file

Comment: [
   [
      "1",
      "000001",
      "Head & Shoulders Shampoo",
      "heads2.jpg",
      "10",
      "100",
      "pcs"
   ],
   [
      "2",
      "000002",
      "Tide bar",
      "20297695.png",
      "100",
      "50",
      "pcs"
   ],
]

Comment: this is a `List` where each item is another `List` where each item is a `String` - something like: `List<List<String>> data` and not `Map data`

Comment: So when you print(response.body);, It shows that right?